# How to understand "Very suave, Robert" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Langdon sighed. Placing his palms flat on the polished parquet, he lay on his stomach and pulled himself forward. As he slid underneath, the nape of his Harris tweed snagged on the bottom of the grate, and he cracked the back of his head on the iron.
>
> ***Very suave, Robert***, he thought, fumbling and then finally pulling himself through. As he stood up, Langdon was beginning to suspect it was going to be a very long night.
>
> <sub>The Da Vinci Code</sub>

I don't quite understand "Very suave, Robert" in the context.  What does it mean here?

Comment: It's ***sarcasm*** (making an assertion when what you *actually* mean is the precise opposite). Like when you do something stupid and someone says ***Oh, that's just great**!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a negative connotation. He's admonishing himself for being so inelegant and clumsy.

Suave: Charming, confident and elegant

Crawling along the ground, snagging his coat & then banging his head was really quite the antithesis to any of those connotations.

If it was Wayne's World, they'd have clarified the joke by adding "…not".

It's a common idiomatic speech type.

- You drop your ice cream… "Oh brilliant! How clever!"
- You trip up a kerb… "Quite the ballet dancer!"
- On your way home from work, you run for the bus & miss it; you splash through a puddle & soak your trousers; you arrive home to remember you left your keys on the kitchen table this morning… "The perfect end to the perfect day!"

Comment: What's "Wayne's World"?

Comment: 1992 Mike Myers comedy - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105793/ it contained a lot of lines that became memes, including such as ["I'm having a good time… not"](https://consequenceofsound.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/im-having-a-good-time-not.gif)